# Symfony DomCrawler can't get attribute

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5, domcrawler

For this div:

```
<section class='menu'>
    <div class="some beautiful classes" link="/some/path/in/web">
        <div class="contImgHome">
            <img src="/images/icon.jpg alt="">
        </div>
        <h5>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Go to Section</a>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="some beautiful classes" link="/another/path/in/web">
        <div class="contImgHome">
            <img src="/images/icon.jpg alt="">
        </div>
        <h5>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Go to another section</a>
        </h5>
    </div>
</section>
```

I make:

```
$response = $guzzleClient->request('GET', $url_base);

$crawler = new Crawler( (string) $response->getBody() );
$crawler->filter('section.menu > div')->each(function( Crawler $div, $i )
{
    $xx = $div->extract( [ 'class', 'link'] );

    print_r( $xx );
    echo PHP_EOL;
    die;

});
```

And return this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some beautiful classes
            [1] =>
        )

)
```

I also tried with:

```
$div->attr('classes');
$div->attr('link');
```

But 'link' attribute is always empty. ¿Why I cant get "link" attribute?

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and installed Symfony Crawler vía composer.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake!

Web set that "link" attribute with javascript using Document Ready, so attr is not existing when Crawler gets page DOM.